# Google Sheets style (Boldface only first line)

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I boldface only first line of a Google Sheet using Python and google-sheets api.

I used this:

```
{  
   "requests":[  
      {  
         "repeatCell":{  
            "range":{  
               "sheetId":0,
               "startRowIndex":0,
               "endRowIndex":1
            },
            "cell":{  
               "userEnteredFormat":{  
                  "textFormat":{  
                     "bold":true
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":"userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But this boldfaces the whole cell.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
{  
   "requests":[  
      {  
         "repeatCell":{  
            "range":{  
               "endRowIndex":1
            },
            "cell":{  
               "userEnteredFormat":{  
                  "textFormat":{  
                     "bold": true
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields":"userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This will bold the first row of the sheet.
For more infos, read the documentation about [range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange) in Google Sheets.

Comment: thanks for that...but that will bold the first row..i want to bold the first line in a cell..e.g two lines in a cell and first one with bold and second without bold

Comment: Then try to add this to your range: startColumnIndex: 0